# Watch Ethereum Smart Contract Events with Node.js App without browser

Tags: node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts

I need to be able to listen to events from a smart contract on the ethereum blockchain. I'd like to use Node.js but it only seem to work if I open the App in my browser. I want the node app to run in the background, listen for events and then do something automatically.

Is this possible or would you recommend any other technology?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a lot of study. Take a look at web3.js, and Events.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Minimal Node.js App with express and web3. Try this repository as a reference, it was very insightful to me: https://github.com/nacmonad/eth-iot-examples/